# Stuck in logon loop

Tags: 10.04, gnome

Here's the deal. I set up a computer with Ubuntu 10.04 for my grandmother. Everything worked fine. I connected it to the internet at her house today. After rebooting the computer I found that the computer would kick you back to the logon screen if you attempted to logon to her account. It worked fine logging on to my admin account, and also in Gnome's safe mode. I thought it had resolved itself, but turns out it hadn't, and now I don't have physical access to the computer, plus the remote connection I'd hoped to use only works intermittently.

I need some suggestions for troubleshooting for when I'm at her house at some point next week. Ask for any more details, but I'm afraid I won't be able to provide many more until I've checked it out in person, since she is basically unable to use a computer beyond web browsing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to delete `~/.gconf`. Had to reset all of the user appearance settings among other things. No idea how it came to be corrupted.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ideas for debugging:

- Are there any odd applications in session startup (`~/.config/autostart`) that may be causing a logout by killing gnome-session prematurely?
- Check `~/.xsession-errors` on the account after it fails to sign in. There should be details of what's going awry.
- If not, check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see if X itself is crashing. This is unlikely, as you mentioned that other accounts could sign in fine.

In the meantime, if any of these suggestions don't root up any problems, I'd create her a clean temporary account to use until you're able to resolve the issue.

Edit: This is assuming you have SSH access; it may be a little difficult to relay these instructions over the phone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try all of these. I've had a look at logs, but I'm not sure which are pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative fix:

1. Switch to terminal screen via: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Login as root
3. `sudo aptitude install gnome-desktop-environment`
4. switch back to Desktop logon screen via: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (in my case)

done

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion above didn't seem to work for me but I found a [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8784206) in the forums that had an answer that worked for me. In my case I would click on the login name and then it would just loop back to the screen.

I tried deleting the `~/.gconf` with no luck, or at least doing that alone wasn't enough. To do this, I switched to the terminal from the login screen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

```
rmdir ~/.gconf
```

The solution seemed to be a forced reinstall of gnome-session, which clearly I must have broke while playing with user or login settings or when I was uninstalling packages I didn't want (Evolution, UbuntuOne).

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
```

And then rebooted with,

```
reboot now
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was due to an xserver upgrade which stoped recognizing my nvidia drivers, which I had installed manually. Fixed the problem by uninstalling them, and installing them again, but maybe it can be fixed faster by deleting xorg.conf from /etc/X11 and running in the terminal nvidia-xconfig

Hope this helps you, or others with the same problem..

Comment: This is good info but it's limited to a very specific use case, and it's not clear from the question that this case applies. When you have more reputation points you can use comments to ask the OP to edit the question to include more information.